# How to add mime-types in embedded jetty

Tags: java, jetty, mime-types, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to add a custom mime-type:

```
ServletContextHandler servletHandler
    = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();
mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("amr", "audio/AMR");
servletHandler.setMimeTypes(mimeTypes);
```

but the amr files are still served without Content-type header.
Here's the actual code:

```
package org.traccar.web;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpMethod;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes;
import org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AsyncProxyServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.AbstractConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.traccar.Config;
import org.traccar.api.AsyncSocketServlet;
import org.traccar.api.CorsResponseFilter;
import org.traccar.api.MediaFilter;
import org.traccar.api.ObjectMapperProvider;
import org.traccar.api.ResourceErrorHandler;
import org.traccar.api.SecurityRequestFilter;
import org.traccar.api.resource.ServerResource;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class WebServer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServer.class);

    private Server server;

    private void initServer(Config config) {

        String address = config.getString("web.address");
        int port = config.getInteger("web.port", 8082);
        if (address == null) {
            server = new Server(port);
        } else {
            server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
        }
    }

    public WebServer(Config config) {

        initServer(config);

        ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        int sessionTimeout = config.getInteger("web.sessionTimeout");
        if (sessionTimeout > 0) {
            servletHandler.getSessionHandler().setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeout);
        }

        initApi(config, servletHandler);

        if (config.getBoolean("web.console")) {
            servletHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ConsoleServlet()), "/console/*");
        }

        initWebApp(config, servletHandler);

        servletHandler.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            protected void handleErrorPage(
                    HttpServletRequest request, Writer writer, int code, String message) throws IOException {
                writer.write("<!DOCTYPE<html><head><title>Error</title></head><html><body>"
                        + code + " - " + HttpStatus.getMessage(code) + "</body></html>");
            }
        });

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        initClientProxy(config, handlers);
        handlers.addHandler(servletHandler);
//        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        server.setHandler(handlers);
    }

    private void initClientProxy(Config config, HandlerList handlers) {
        int port = config.getInteger("osmand.port");
        if (port != 0) {
            ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler() {
                @Override
                public void doScope(
                        String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws IOException, ServletException {
                    if (target.equals("/") && request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST.asString())) {
                        super.doScope(target, baseRequest, request, response);
                    }
                }
            };
            ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new AsyncProxyServlet.Transparent());
            servletHolder.setInitParameter("proxyTo", "http://localhost:" + port);
            servletHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/");
            handlers.addHandler(servletHandler);
        }
    }

    private void initWebApp(Config config, ServletContextHandler servletHandler) {
        ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(DefaultServlet.class);
        servletHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", config.getString("web.path"));
        if (config.getBoolean("web.debug")) {
            servletHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"debug.html", "index.html"});
        } else {
            String cache = config.getString("web.cacheControl");
            if (cache != null && !cache.isEmpty()) {
                servletHolder.setInitParameter("cacheControl", cache);
            }
            servletHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] {"release.html", "index.html"});
        }
        servletHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
    }

    private void initApi(Config config, ServletContextHandler servletHandler) {
        servletHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new AsyncSocketServlet()), "/api/socket");

        if (config.hasKey("media.path")) {
            ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(DefaultServlet.class);
            servletHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", config.getString("media.path"));
            servletHolder.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", config.getString("media.dirAllowed", "false"));
            servletHolder.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
            servletHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/api/media/*");
            servletHandler.addFilter(MediaFilter.class, "/api/media/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));

//            Set<String> knownMimeTypes = MimeTypes.getKnownMimeTypes();
//            MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();
//            mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("amr", "audio/AMR");
//            servletHandler.setMimeTypes(mimeTypes);

            servletHandler.getMimeTypes().addMimeMapping("amr", "audio/AMR");
        }

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.registerClasses(JacksonFeature.class, ObjectMapperProvider.class, ResourceErrorHandler.class);
        resourceConfig.registerClasses(SecurityRequestFilter.class, CorsResponseFilter.class);
        resourceConfig.packages(ServerResource.class.getPackage().getName());
        servletHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/api/*");

    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            LOGGER.warn("Web server start failed", error);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            server.stop();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            LOGGER.warn("Web server stop failed", error);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace the `MimeTypes`, modify the existing one.

Example:

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.PathResource;

public class MimeTypeCustomDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");
        Path webRootPath = Paths.get("src","test", "resources", "webroot");
        if(Files.notExists(webRootPath)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(webRootPath.toString());
        }
        context.setBaseResource(new PathResource(webRootPath));
        context.getMimeTypes().addMimeMapping("amr", "audio/AMR");

        ServletHolder defHolder = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
        context.addServlet(defHolder, "/");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(context);
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        try {
            server.start();
            testGet(server.getURI().resolve("/example.amr"));
        } finally {
            server.stop();
        }
    }

    private static void testGet(URI uri) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();
        dumpRequestResponse(http);
    }

    private static void dumpRequestResponse(HttpURLConnection http) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.printf("%s %s HTTP/1.1%n", http.getRequestMethod(), http.getURL());
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.printf("%s%n", http.getHeaderField(null));
        http.getHeaderFields().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() != null)
                .forEach((entry) -> System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", entry.getKey(), http.getHeaderField(entry.getKey())));
    }
}
```

This results in ...

```
2019-01-09 13:20:10.178:INFO::main: Logging initialized @167ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-01-09 13:20:10.277:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.12.v20180830; built: 2018-08-30T13:59:14.071Z; git: 27208684755d94a92186989f695db2d7b21ebc51; jvm 1.8.0_192-b12
2019-01-09 13:20:10.293:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@614c5515{/,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty-demos/src/test/resources/webroot/,AVAILABLE}
2019-01-09 13:20:10.305:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@61dc03ce{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-01-09 13:20:10.306:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @296ms

----
GET http://127.0.1.1:8080/example.amr HTTP/1.1
----
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Jetty(9.4.12.v20180830)
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 19:19:50 GMT
Content-Length: 200222
Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 19:20:10 GMT
Content-Type: audio/amr
2019-01-09 13:20:10.390:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Stopped ServerConnector@61dc03ce{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-01-09 13:20:10.392:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@614c5515{/,file:///home/joakim/code/jetty-demos/src/test/resources/webroot/,UNAVAILABLE}
```

Comment: Adding the mime type didn't help (not surprised, because then it would've worked for the amr files even in my example, just not for the rest of the files)). I added the actual code. It looks very similar to yours, maybe the difference is that it doesn't use the DefaultHandler. Any idea why it doesn't add the mime-type?

Comment: `DefaultHandler` (at the end of the handler list) is a error handler, producing a clear error when you have something wrong with your prior handlers.

Comment: `MimeTypes` are used by the `DefaultServlet` to serve static content, and to handle response character encoding for your web apps dynamic servlets.  If  you are using neither of those, then `MimeTypes` has no impact on your results.  This is especially true when using libraries that think they have to serve static files themselves (a colossally bad idea!) such as Jersey, Spring Boot, and Spark. (static file serving by the container is always more resource friendly then by a web application)

Comment: I see, this explains it, because in my case there's a filter that checks permissions (everyone can only download files in their directory)